# Erro no registro de um banco Firebird 2.0 no IBExpert

Tags: firebird

Estou com dificultes para registrar um banco de dados Firebird 2.0 no IBExpert.
Agradeço a ajuda!

Estão acontecendo os seguintes erros:

**Tentativa 01**

```
Attempting to connect to:
localhost:C:\Proviser\SGDB\Proviser.GDB
Connecting... Failed!
```

> Client Library is missing or invalid: C:\Program
>   Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\bin\gds32.dll
>   Notice, that you have to use 32-bit client library even if you connect
>   to 64-bit version of Firebird/InterBase because IBExpert is a 32-bit
>   application. In case you specify a 64-bit version of client library
>   dll instead of 32-bit one you can get this error.

```
Attempting to connect to services manager... Failed!
```

> Client Library is missing or invalid: C:\Program
>   Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\bin\gds32.dll Notice, that you have to use
>   32-bit client library even if you connect to 64-bit version of
>   Firebird/InterBase because IBExpert is a 32-bit application. In case
>   you specify a 64-bit version of client library dll instead of 32-bit
>   one you can get this error.

`Disconnecting from database... Passed!`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tentativa 02**

`Attempting to connect to: localhost:C:\Proviser\SGDB\Proviser.GDB
Connecting... Failed!`

> wrong or obsolete version.
>   unsupported on-disk structure for file C:\Proviser\SGDB\Proviser.GDB; found > > 32779.10, support 0.28.

`Attempting to connect to services manager... Passed!
Disconnecting from database... Passed!`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparentemente é um problema de conflito de DLL's. Você está usando a versão mais atual do Firebird?

Comment: Este banco foi feito na versão 2.0 do Firebird, eu teria que ter a mais atual?

Comment: Era bom. Como as DLL's estão em versões diferentes, o Client do Firebird está se perdendo.

Answer (score 2):

O problema relatado geralmente ocorre quando o sistema operacional é 64bits...

Em uma resposta simples, eu apago o caminho completo do Client Library,  deixando o nome do arquivo da dll..., e o ibexpert vai buscar relativamente a dll do firebird.

**Client Library File**

**Antes:** C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\bin\gds32.dll

**Depois:** gds32.dll

**Ou**

**Antes:** C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\bin\fbclient.dll

**Depois:** fbclient.dll

**Obs.:** Resolva o problema de conexão antes de tentar converter a versão do banco...

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro erro ocorre pois o arquivo gds32.dll não estava disponível na versão utilizada pelo IBExpert que é 32 bits.

O segundo erro ocorre porque, embora a biblioteca fbclient.dll esteja disponível, você está tentando acessar uma base de dados do Firebird ou do Interbase que é mais atual do que o Firebird instalado. Se sua versão instalada é do Firebird 2.0 conforme mostra o caminho das pastas, esse banco **não** está mais na versão do Firebird 2.0. Talvez ele tenha sido gerado no Firebired 2.0, mas passado por alguma atualização de seu ODS (On Disk Structure).

Posso estar enganado, mas provavelmente, sua base de dados é do Firebird 2.1. Então seria melhor você instalar essa versão do Firebird ou alguma mais atual nesta máquina, para acessar o banco de dados. Outra possibilidade é ele estar numa versão do Interbase, que tem uma ODS similar ao do Firebird.